# Search strategy for online application

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene.net, graph-databases

- I have an application with around 700 000 active products with actual stock quantity.
- Each product can have multiple attributes and categories.
- Product name, description and attributes can be delivered to the user in a few languages.

What I need to achive is fast search. By fast I mean that for example for product group which contains 250k of products I would like to return a first page of sorted results in 100ms.

My first thought was to deformalize data and push it into document db like elastic search. But there is one issue - **product price**: it depends on the user that is actually logged in.

Currently there will be 30k users. Each user can have different discount for each product category or even for each particular product. When discount or price is changed there is a business requirement to synchronize prices in a few minutes. Potentially system could compute prices for search results on fly, but there is an issue with sorting and pagination. When group consist of 250k products it will be hard to get results, compute price, sort and return given page.

Is there any way to return user dependent field in elastic search? Or I should rather start looking into some other solutions like graph databases?

Comment: `When group consist of 250k products it will be hard to get results, compute price, sort and return given page.` And you think that a page of 250k products will be useful?

Comment: It was about scenario when system computes price after discount on server side. For example system get products from elastic search and then 'personalize' prices. After that you can sort by price and take the page with for example 50 products from the list.

Comment: What's the definition of an user from Elasticsearch point of view? Also, how do track the discounts of each user and, in general, the particularities prices need to have for each user?

Comment: In the context of product and price user is just a factor that affects price. Currently I have a table that stores prices computed per user. If discount changed system recomputes prices (computing a price is quite complecated, there are many additional factors). Don't need to bother now about changes of product price - it happens rare.

Comment: Yes, you do because depending on the complexity of the calculations, you either do them at search time (in the query itself) or you update the documents somehow (but that's not feasible).